# How to fetch the last row MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 100k Data; this is all just my example

I have this 2 tables

I want to check into my table2 if the schedule exists in my table1.

If it exists the last schedule will be the output with remarks = 'OK' and Balance = '0'

my sample query:

```
select * 
from table2 as A
join table1 as B ON A.ID = B.ID
where A.Remarks = 'OK'  
  and A.Schedule = (select max(schedule) from table1)
  and A.balance = '0' 
  and B.Balance = 0
```

the output should be like this

| ID | Schedule | BALANCE | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | OK |

TABLE1

| ID | Schedule | BALANCE | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | OK |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | OK |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | OK |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | OK |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | OK |
| 2 | 6 | 100 | NOT_OK |

TABLE2

| ID | Schedule | BALANCE | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | OK |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | OK |

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (select max(schedule) from table1) - always returns 6

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A.ID,
       max(B.Schedule),
       A.Balance,
       A.Remarks 
from table2 as A
join table1 as B ON A.ID = B.ID
Where A.Remarks = 'OK'
  and A.Balance = '0' 
  and B.Balance = 0 
Group By A.ID,
         A.Balance,
         A.Remarks
```

Comment: Hello i think the output of this just like
max(A.schedule) but i want to stick into my output which is max(B.Schedule) and schedule #5

Comment: In this example it is not important A.schedule or B.schedule. When you change it I think it will be same result.